# Collection View cell in Swift is not formatting correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to Swift and I am trying to create a `UICollectionViewCell`. It builds successfully but the cells are not the size that I thought I was creating. There are supposed to be two columns and and it is supposed to contain an image, description and price. I know it is something simple but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. See the image below. I assume I need to fix something in the size inspector but I cannot figure out what.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ProductsVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    @IBOutlet weak var productsCollection: UICollectionView!

    private(set) public var products = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        productsCollection.dataSource = self
        productsCollection.delegate = self
    }

    func initProducts(category: Category){
        products = DataService.instance.getProducts(forCategoryTitle: category.title)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductCell {
            let product = products[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateViews(product: product)
            return cell
        }
        return ProductCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height: CGFloat = 280
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 10) / 2, height: height)
        //10 is minimum line spacing between two columns
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I have only used the size inspector and auto layout for constraints. Therefor I do not have any code to show that I believe pertains to the size of the cells. I can certainly post my code for the view and controller. Sorry for what appears to be a poorly written question! Swift is so different than the other languages I have learned.

Comment: Have a peek at `intrinsicContentSize` for setting your sizes on the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FYI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout)

Try this:

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // You can change collection view cell height here, It's up to your design
        let height: CGFloat = 150
        let width: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.size.width - 10 - a) / 2 // a is extra spacing of collection view (like leading or trailing constraints)
        // Converting CGFloat to Int make sure the width of total cells are less than or equal the screen width
        return CGSize(width: Int(width), height: Int(height)) // 10 is minimum line spacing between two columns
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
}
```

**Please check extra spacings example with the below photo:**

a = 20 with my example design (leading = 10, trailing = 10)
[image]

Comment: please provide some explanation of why this would work.

Comment: FYI https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

Comment: Thanks for the response Tam-Thanh Le and welcome to SO! I tried your solution and it appears to work accept the view cells show up in what appears to be a tableview. Why is that and how can I fix it? You can see my updated code in my original question above.

Comment: Maybe there is some extra spacing of the collection view (like leading or trailing constraints). I updated my above answer. Please check

Comment: I finally figured out what the issue was. In the collection view size inspector, I had the "automatic" selected instead of "none". Once I selected "none" the code executed correctly. Thanks for the help Tam-Thanh Le!

Comment: Yes Awesome It should be none and would be working correctly

Comment: I updated my above code. Maybe It would be broken with some devices, please update it into your code

Answer (score 1):

just provide the `itemSize` when you declare the `collectionView`:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = sizeForEachItem
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```